# High Speed file transmission through WIFI

Tags: java, android, sockets

everyone. I am a beginner in network programming. Currently, I want to do an experiment which sends a file(~2M bytes) from Android phone to Ubuntu server. How can I send it at the highest speed? I have tried something like using Bufferedreader in Java, reading each byte out of the file and sending that single byte to server through socket "outputstream write" function. This way seems to cost too much time. I notice that if in the same network condition, I send same file using some Immediate Messenger tools,like Skype;it is much quicker than I did. Does anybody know the API or implementation protocol beneath those Immediate Messenger software?

I probably need to call other efficient APIs other than socket? I am also trying to read the whole file into a byte array and then call "socket write" function to send the huge byte array to server for a just single time.Although when I receive it at server side to found that there are a lot of "padding zeros" distributed in my original data, the whole transfer seems to cost less time than the "single byte transfer" method. Anybody has any advice on this?Thanks a lot!

Comment: It makes no sense what you say about the "padding zeros". You should adhere to the value returns by any read not the buffer's size. If you do, for example `bRead=socket.read(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));` then you should write bRead bytes to the file not the buffer's size.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everybody's answer. I think I just made a silly mistake. The real reason for my slow transmission using TCP socket is that every time I just read a single byte out of the file and call "void write(int b)" to send this single byte to server.This method is very time consuming. Now every time I try to read 256 bytes out of file and send these 256 bytes through "void write(byte[] b,int off,int len)";in this way, the transmission is pretty fast.Therefore, it is not the problem of TCP itself. It is my mistake of calling the wrong API. I have not tried UDP yet. But I think it is also a good choice.Thanks again,everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Short of reinventing TCP/IP the fastest way to send will be via UDP, if your connection is good enough (few losses) than you on;y need to implement packet sequence so the sender prepends sequence number to the data packets, the receiver keeps track of missed packets and requests them again after all data is sent. After all data is received the receiver can reassemble the complete file.

This is simplistic implementation of TCP over UDP.

Comment: Could you please give some API? I could search and use it in Android.Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no additional API. It is DatagramSocket <-> Socket connection, https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+datagramsocket